# Update the JSF bean even if the validation fails?

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

JSF beans are generally not updated when the validation fails, which in some cases causes really ugly effects, for example, when using `facet="output"` of `p:inplace`:

```xml
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="3" cellpadding="2">
  <p:outputLabel value="My Field" for="myfield" />
  <p:inputText id="myfield" value="#{test.myField}" required="true" />
  <p:message for="myfield" />

  <h:outputText value="Checkbox: " />
  <p:inplace id="checkboxInplace" effect="none">
    <f:facet name="output">#{test.myBooleanText}</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{test.myBoolean}" />
    </f:facet>
  </p:inplace>
  <p:spacer />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton id="refresh" icon="ui-icon-refresh" update="panel" process="@form"/>
</h:form>
```

The output facet defines the inplace labels, which should be localized instead of standard ones:

```java
private boolean myBoolean;

public String getMyBooleanText() {
    return myBoolean ? "Ja" : "Nein";
}
```

However, when the validation fails, the inplace output facet shows the old value of the checkbox, not the actual one. If you click on it, a real value is shown.

How to solve that issue and actualize the output correctly? Submiting the values to the bean would be the best, because I have no problem with consistent state of values on the client and server, as long no action is actually executed (asserted by the validation).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but give this a chance:

```
<p:inplace id="checkboxInplace" effect="none">
    <f:facet name="output">#{test.myBoolean ? 'Ja' : 'Nein'}</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{test.myBoolean}" immediate="true">
            <p:ajax update="@parent" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox />
    </f:facet>
</p:inplace>
```

Comment: It's the same. EL isn't re-executed, but the values of the input are preserved on the client-side.

Comment: What happens if you remove the facets? Just the select boolean inside the inplace.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work correctly without a facet. It shows always empty label...